# Is there any way to get a snapshot of docker stats?

Tags: docker

By default `docker stats` produces streaming output.  Is there any way to get a single snapshot of the stats output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`docker stats`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/) has the `--no-stream` argument

```
docker stats --no-stream container_name
```

You can get the extended usage information for each of the docker commands with `docker help <command_name>` and the list of all commands with `docker help`